# Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1 unable to install as windows service

Tags: database, windows, service, windows-services, neo4j

I used to install Neo4j 2.0.0-M05 as windows service, this worked great. With 2.0.0-RC1 it doesn't any more.

## Intro

With 2.0.0-RC1 I can download an installer. Seems that this installer does not have an option to install Neo4j as service. Also it doesn't let you set some directories (I like everything in C:\apache\neo4j); some stuff is being stored in my user directory. And it doesn't remember the location of the database. So that leaves the zip as only real alternative, though the zip file comes in only one version while the installer comes in 32bits and 64bits??
Anyway now trying with the zip package I have to run a .bat file just as before (i'm used to this). But when i try install, i get:

```
C:\apache\neo4j\bin>Neo4jInstaller.bat install
"WARNING: this installer is deprecated and may not be the optimal way to install Neo4j on your system."
"Please see the Neo4j Manual for up to date information on installing Neo4j."
Press any key to continue
```

Two things are weird.

1. It's the only option to install neo4j as service, so how can it be deprecated?
2. Press any key to continue only response to the enter key.

## Problem

Continuing on the the real problem:

```
Press any key to continue
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED 87:

The parameter is incorrect.
```

## Workaround

I removed the .bat files from 2.0.0-RC1 and copied the 2.0.0-M05 bat files over to the new version. It seems to start the new version without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. There are open github issues related to much of this, which we'll clean up before going to GA. Even then, your conclusion is correct, that for now installation as a service requires downloading the .zip distribution. We'll make that more clear in the download page.

Generally, installation as a windows service is something we're working to improve. I'd love to chat with you a bit about your particular deployment scenario. Please drop me a line at andreas@neotechnology.com.

Best,
Andreas